# <%= current_user.role %> evaluates to nothing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, view

I'm making a Rails app and am trying to have the user's role displayed on a view. The code I am using for this is:

```
<%= current_user.role %>
```

Which does not evaluate to anything.

I am using devise for user registrations and my registration view is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="login-field">
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="login-field">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Password (8 character min)"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="login-field">
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, :placeholder => "First Name"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="login-field">
        <%= f.text_field :lastname, :placeholder => "Last Name"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="login-field">
        <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone Number"  %>
    </div>

    <%= f.select(:role, ['Role 1', 'Role 2', 'Both']) %>

    <br>

    <div><%= f.submit "Signup" , :class => "btn btn-success btn-lg" %></div>

  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong in the form submission but cannot figure out what it is. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `sign_up_params` in the Devise registration. Once you've created your `RegistrationsController` that inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController`, you can override the `sign_up_params`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :role ... any other attributes)
  end

end
```

You would also need to change you `routes.rb` to point to the newly created controller:

`devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}`

Comment: I did what you said but its still not generating anything.

Comment: Is it setting the `phone` attribute?

Comment: Its only setting email and password it seems

Comment: Try to debug to see if it is using the new controller. Make sure you modified the `devise_for` in the routes.rb.

Comment: I changed the devise_for in routes.rb. Sorry Im a but of a rails noob, how do I debug to check to see if I'm using the new controller?

Comment: put `5.times { logger.info 'in custom registration controller' }` above `params.require ...` and see if they show up in logs. Or put `raise_error 'In New controller'` and see if you get an error

Comment: An error does get raised, I guess it is using the new controller, strange

Answer (score 0):

You can put this at the top of your `create` `action`:

```
return render text: params.inspect # get what the form sended
```

and or

```
return render text: create_params # get what the values you permitted
```

This way you will get what the data your from sended and if it is what you expected.